# How does ASP.NET timeout actually work?

Tags: asp.net, .net, timeout

The [`Server.ScriptTimout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout.aspx) value controls how much time is allowed for an HTTP request to execute. The default is 90 seconds.

I'm really unclear on what this timeout setting causes to happen:

1. What happens after the timeout has elapsed?
2. What does ASP.NET do to enforce the timeout?
3. Does ASP.NET abort the request thread?
4. Does it terminate the connection to the HTTP client?
5. What happens if the request is not abortable or does not use any thread at the moment (e.g. `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);` or `await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);`)?

These questions are hard to answer by experiment because you never know what cases you might have missed.